# Passing of Web Scraping Data

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently writing an application that will extract data from a few different websites to be passed back to my app, parsed, formatted, and displayed. The problem I keep running into is being able to pass in and display the data in a graphical manner. I was hoping to use HTML5 to do this, and all of my scraping is set up in php. Of course, to draw in HTML5 requires using JavaScript, and getting my php output to JavaScript seems messy. Am I missing a better way to architect this solution?

Comment: are you looking to graph the data that you scrape? or display it in another way?

Comment: Another way. I'm semantically picking a design, but think things like timelines, bubble charts, etc. Not typical line graphs and scatter plots - more graphics-intensive.

Comment: i assume you got permission to use other peoples property.

Comment: Yes, this is for a University website, working off of several people in a department.

Comment: scraping is a poor way to share data in such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a good way to me, as good as any, except it's not very backwards compatible, it might be better to do the graphing server side

Comment: How would one switch the graphing to the server side? In the end, I need an image produced, and I'm not entirely sure how to do that without using HTML5s `canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do graphics directly in php you may want to look at using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).